# Incorrect formatting of file when calling nvim inside NodeJS script

Tags: formatting, microsoft-windows, cmdline

I am formatting `elixir` files `.ex` with the help of a contributed plug-in for `nvim` like this on Windows:

```
cmd> nvim.exe -i NONE -n -E +"norm gg=G" -cwq c:/file.ex
```

This works fine when the command is called inside normal Windows command line prompt. However, if I run the same command in NodeJS using `child_process` the formatting gets wrong (not proper indentations).

Correct formatting:

```
defmodule BackendWeb.Endpoint do
  def go do
    IO.puts "go"
  end
end
```

Faulty formatting:

```
defmodule BackendWeb.Endpoint do
def go do
IO.puts "go"
end
end
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

**Update**

This formats the file badly:

```
require('child_process').exec('C:/opt/neovim/bin/nvim.exe -i NONE -n -E +"norm gg=G" -cwq ' + path, function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

This formats the file properly:

```
require('child_process').exec('start /MIN C:/opt/neovim/bin/nvim.exe -i NONE -n -E +"norm gg=G" -cwq ' + path, function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

Using `start /MIN` to run `nvim` solved the problem, but it creates for fraction of a second some task bar item (minified window).

Comment: working workaround.. I have created a simple `c#` console application which executes the above code line using `Process()`. From `NodeJS`, calling that `c#` executable formats the file just fine.. Maybe this issue is not related to `vim` at all, and has to do with some interaction between `NodeJS` and `Windows shell`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the formatting/indentation is wrong? Sounds strange.

Comment: Solved perfectly with no cmd windows by `cmdow.exe /run /hid C:/opt/neovim/bin/nvim.exe -i NONE -n -E +"norm gg=G" -cwq [path-to-file]`. Utility found at: https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/

Comment: At a guess: Is node running as a different user? Does it work using the following as the first argument to `exec()`? `'cmd /C "SET HOME=[path\to\home] && C:/opt/neovim/bin/nvim.exe -i NONE -n -E +"""norm gg=G""" -cwq ' + path + '"'`

Comment: @Rich no, I am getting same faulty formatting. Formatting is correct when doing either 1) removing `-E` from arguments but then the execution takes some 2-3 seconds or 2) running `nvim.exe` with -E in argument list by `start /MIN` or `cmdow.exe /run /hid`

Comment: @W.M. Then I'm stumped. Probably worth updating your question with that info in case future readers miss it.